# How to compare a json with a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv, compare

I have one json payload which is used for one service request. After processing that payload(JSON) will be stored in S3 and through Athena we can download those data in CSV format. Now in the actual scenario, there are more than 100 fields. I want to verify their value through some automated script instead of manual.

say my sample payload is similar to the following:

```
{
  "BOOK": {
    "serialno": "123",
    "author": "xyz",
    "yearofpublish": "2015",
    "price": "16"
  }, "Author": [
    {
      "isbn": "xxxxx", "title": "first", "publisher": "xyz", "year": "2020"
    }, {
      "isbn": "yyyy", "title": "second", "publisher": "zmy", "year": "2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

the sample csv will be like following:
[image]

Can anyone please help me how exactly I can do it on Python? Maybe the library or dictionary?

Comment: Please review your JSON example. It's not valid.

Comment: Yeah. This I just made some random example similar to actual payload where both jsonObject and jsonArray are there. Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you just want to flatten out the JSON structure. It'll be easiest to loop over the "Author" list. Since the CSV has renamed the columns you'll need some way to represent that mapping. Based only on example, this works:

```
import json
fin=open(some_json_file, 'r')
j=json.load(fin)
result=[]
for author in j['Author']:
    val = {'book_serialno':       j['BOOK']['serialno'],
           'book_author':         j['BOOK']['author'],
           'book_yearofpublish':  j['BOOK']['yearofpublish'],
           'book_price':          j['BOOK']['price'],
           'author_isbn':         author['isbn'], 
           'author_title':        author['title'],
           'author_publisher':    author['publisher'],
           'author_year':         author['year']}
    result.append(val)
```

This is using a dictionary to show the mapping of data points to the new column names. You might be able to get away with using a list as well. Depends how you want to use it later on. To write to a CSV:

```
import csv
fout=open(some_csv_file, 'w')
writer=csv.writer(fout)
writer.writerow(result[0].keys())
writer.writerows(r.values() for r in result)
```

This writes the column names in the first row, then the data. If you don't want the column names, just leave out the `writerow(...)` line.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I shall try this. Jst one more query. If I want to skip anyone or two fields during comparing, how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to leave out a field, just remove it from val.

Comment: I have tried the code above, it is losing one of the author object while creating the result       [{'book_serialno': '123', 'book_author': 'xyz', 'book_yearofpublish': '2015', 'book_price': '16', 'author_isbn': 'yyyy', 'author_title': 'second', 'author_publisher': 'zmy', 'author_year': '2019'}]

Comment: if result.append(val) is in same indentation then the problem will be resolved

Comment: But why some extra blank line is adding in the .csv file that I am still trying to figure out.

Comment: good catch on the indent error for the `append`, i updated that. I don't get any empty lines when I copy/paste the above code (substituting in for `some_json_file` and `some_csv_file` of course), using as input the JSON from the question.